# Is ejs front-end or back-end?

Tags: ejs

Newbie question: I'm learning the MEAN stack and is use EJS (embedded javascript) as the template engine.  It's website says its a "cleans the HTML out of your JavaScript with client side templates" but it seems like to me that the <%= %> and <% %> are compiled on the backend and sent to the client afterwards.  Am I not understanding something?

Answer (score 2):

EJS work for both server side and client side.

Personally i use it with nodejs ( server side ), and for the client side my choice is http://mustache.github.io feel comfortable with it.

Comment: Could you provide example of frontend use?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, EJS is a server-side language.  Works kind of like JSP or PHP.

Comment: please accept the correct answer, one answer says its both one says its server-side